# php debuggers which are not bloated

Tags: php, debugging, notepad++

any suggestions for good php debuggers, which are not bloated?

i tried using xdebug with dbgp plugin on notepad++, but it seems the dbgp plugin isn't compatible with notepad++ and hence, didn't work out crashing the app every time i accessed the debugger. any other suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest editing your question.  It's pretty subjective and specific to your failed setup.  

xdebug is a great php debugger, btw.

Comment: you're right. there was nothing specifically wrong with xdebug but with the dbgp incompatibility with notepad++...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure it would qualify as "not-bloated", but I'm generally using Eclipse PDT *(along with Xdebug)*, and it's working well.

I know colleagues who use netbeans, and are satisfied with it too *(tried it MySQL a couple of times, didn't feel bad)*.

Maybe they are a bit heavy, yes... But they are full IDE, under active development, maintained, ... so, not a bad choice, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you only want open source or free software. 
But in our company we use....
[nusphere](http://www.nusphere.com/). It is good. 
but if you want free / opensource then [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/galileo/SR2/eclipse-php-galileo-SR2-win32.zip) is also very good. 
[Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) is good but its little bit heavy.

And yes....this both are full IDE.